# Numpy parse dates with genfromtext

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to load some csv data with numpy's genfromtxt. I'm struggling with the right datatype for the time field. 
For both versions of parse_time I get the same error that says

> Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to  according
>   to the rule 'same_kind'

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

parse_time  = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x.decode('utf-8'), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
parse_time2 = lambda x: np.datetime64(dt.datetime.strptime(x.decode('utf-8'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
col_names = ['Time','Temperature','Humidity']
lines = ['2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0', '2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0']

np.genfromtxt(lines, delimiter=';',dtype=[('Time',"datetime64"),('Temperature','f'),('Humidity','f')], converters={"Time": parse_time2},names=col_names)
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-cd725618b291> in <module>
      7 lines = ['2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0', '2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0']
      8 
----> 9 a = np.genfromtxt(lines, delimiter=';',dtype=[('Time',"datetime64"),('Temperature','f'),('Humidity','f')], converters={"Time": parse_time},names=col_names)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows, encoding)
   2163                     output = np.array(data, dtype=dtype)
   2164             else:
-> 2165                 rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
   2166                 output = rows.view(dtype)
   2167             # Now, process the rowmasks the same way

TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: Change the dtype: `('Time',"datetime64[us]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hpaulj commented, changing the datatype to datetime64[us] solves it:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

parse_time  = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x.decode('utf-8'), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
parse_time2 = lambda x: np.datetime64(dt.datetime.strptime(x.decode('utf-8'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
col_names = ['Time','Temperature','Humidity']
lines = ['2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0', '2018-10-03T11:28:35.325Z;23.0;17.0']

np.genfromtxt(lines, delimiter=';',dtype=[('Time',"datetime64[us]"),('Temperature','f'),('Humidity','f')], converters={"Time": parse_time2},names=col_names)
```